# Load balance for Java NIO server

Tags: java, load-balancing, nio, ems

We have an application service which has two instances running on two separate servers. The instances are exactly the same but for load balancing.

We use EMS for client/server communication. Both service instances consumes the same EMS queue, therefore a message(task) in the EMS queue ends up in once of the two instances. The load is balanced reasonably well.

However, due to performance issue, we are planning to change from EMS to NIO based server. With NIO server, the load balance granted by EMS is no longer available.

My question is that what is the ideal way we can load balance client requests to multiple NIO servers?

Comment: there is a journal here: http://www.iaesjournal.com/ojs237/index.php/TELKOMNIKA/article/viewFile/1431/pdf

Comment: I doubt that this proposed change is well motivated. But there are plenty of hardware load balancing solutions available.

Comment: nginx or cloud elb